# "Translated foreign pages" has been discontinued. Are there any alternatives to it?

Tags: web-apps, search-engine, translation

I used to rely on Google's "translated foreign pages" tool, but it was [discontinued in May 2013](http://searchengineland.com/google-drops-translated-foreign-pages-search-option-due-to-lack-of-use-160157). Are there any other search engines that can retrieve search results in multiple languages using translated search queries?

I was using this tool to cross-reference articles on Wikipedia in several different languages, but I now have no suitable tool for this task.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: @Izzy This question already describes the feature that I'm looking for: "Are there any other search engines that can retrieve text in multiple languages using translated search queries?".

Comment: How do you specify which texts it should retrieve: search terms, URLs, ...? What format do you expect them to return: list of URLs, multi-column text, XML, some other specific format? First thing coming to my mind is [Linguee](http://www.linguee.de/), but that rather focuses on search terms than on specific articles (and AFAIK only gives "German <-> otherLang").

Comment: @Izzy "Translated foreign pages" had the same format as any other Google search results page, containing a list of links and page descriptions. This is the format that is used by most web search engines.

Comment: Hm. Could you take a look at linguee.de then? Would that fit your requirements? That's what I use frequently. It doesn't translate itself, but checks for multi-lingual sites and puts the relevant phrases next to each other, so you get some context on your search terms.

Answer (score -1):

There is a search engine called [2lingual](http://www.2lingual.com/) that can provide translated search results in multiple languages. The search engine uses Google to provide its results, so it is very similar to the "translated foreign pages" feature.

Comment: How does this help? It searches for pages written in one of two languages. It does not translate the resultant pages as OP requested.

Comment: @Mawg This solution isn't ideal, but it's the best one that I have found so far. Fortunately, there are several [command-line translators](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=command+line+translator&oq=command+line+translator&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30l8.1167552.2008204.0.2008475.51.39.2.7.7.0.267.4328.12j17j4.33.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..9.40.4080.0.T06XCituhoo) that can be used to generate a list of Google search queries in multiple languages. Instead of writing a new search engine, I would only need to write a script that generated a list of search URLs.